# Python plots of y with unique intervals for same x axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, graph

I have x and y data that I wish to plot. There are several sets of this data. Each data set has a unique range of validity, outside of which I do not wish to plot.

For example, I have my set of values for the x-axis:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2000, 1000)
```

and

```
y1 = x     # Valid 300 < x < 500
y2 = 2x    # Valid 500 < x < 700
y3 = 3x    # Valid 200 < x < 1500
```

how can I make the vectors y1, y2, y3 only exist on their range of validity with their associated vector of corresponding x-values? I wish to plot them all on the same graph but not using matplotlib

Perhaps np.select somehow?

Comment: why are you uninterested in a matplotlib answer?

Comment: because Plotly looks way nicer

Comment: I suggest you post some plotly code of your attempted solution with an example (arbitrary) dataset, and highlight where you got stuck. Then I or someone else will provide a solution for where you are stuck.